# When using shell inside Docker, previous command (Ctrl+P) does not refresh

Tags: shell, zsh, docker

I'm new to Docker, and I had a running container with Ubuntu 16.

I usually connect the container with the command:

```
docker exec -it 7e3 /usr/bin/zsh
```

Then, when I use the shell inside the Docker,
when I type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to show the previous command,
the Terminal did not refresh and nothing shows. 
I have to press something else to make it refresh. 
My Terminal is iTerm on macOS Mojave.

I did some search on Google, such as "docker shell not refresh",
but I could not find anything useful.

Comment: Please see top 1 answer from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20828657/docker-change-ctrlp-to-something-else, it works for me.